# First Column Scroll and Table Filter Function not Synchronized

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I haven't coded in a while, and I'm relatively new to javascript, so apologies if this is a dumb question.

Basically, I wrote code for an HTML table that filters the table based on items in the first column *and* allows both the first column and header to remain fixed if the Table overflows and you have to scroll.

The problem I'm having is that when you search for an item, it works and shows up, but then when you scroll horizontally, the item in the first column reverts to the very first item in the first column. So, for example, if the first column is, in descending order, A, B, C, and D, if you search D and then scroll horizontally, A appears in the first column.

I'm fairly stuck and any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Here's my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('table').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('thead').length > 0 && $(this).find('th').length > 0) {
      // Clone <thead>
      var $w = $(window),
        $t = $(this),
        $thead = $t.find('thead').clone(),
        $col = $t.find('thead, tbody').clone();

      $t
        .addClass('sticky-enabled')
        .css({
          margin: 0,
          width: '100%'
        }).wrap('<div class="sticky-wrap" />');

      if ($t.hasClass('overflow-y')) $t.removeClass('overflow-y').parent().addClass('overflow-y');

      $t.after('<table class="sticky-thead" />');

      if ($t.find('tbody th').length > 0) {
        $t.after('<table class="sticky-col" /><table class="sticky-intersect" />');
      }

      var $stickyHead = $(this).siblings('.sticky-thead'),
        $stickyCol = $(this).siblings('.sticky-col'),
        $stickyInsct = $(this).siblings('.sticky-intersect'),
        $stickyWrap = $(this).parent('.sticky-wrap');

      $stickyHead.append($thead);

      $stickyCol
        .append($col)
        .find('thead th:gt(0)').remove()
        .end()
        .find('tbody td').remove();

      $stickyInsct.html('<thead><tr><th>' + $t.find('thead th:first-child').html() + '</th></tr></thead>');

      var setWidths = function() {
          $t
            .find('thead th').each(function(i) {
              $stickyHead.find('th').eq(i).width($(this).width());
            })
            .end()
            .find('tr').each(function(i) {
              $stickyCol.find('tr').eq(i).height($(this).height());
            });


          $stickyHead.width($t.width());


          $stickyCol.find('th').add($stickyInsct.find('th')).width($t.find('thead th').width())
        },
        repositionStickyHead = function() {

          var allowance = calcAllowance();


          if ($t.height() > $stickyWrap.height()) {

            if ($stickyWrap.scrollTop() > 0) {

              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 1,
                top: $stickyWrap.scrollTop()
              });
            } else {

              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 0,
                top: 0
              });
            }
          } else {

            if ($w.scrollTop() > $t.offset().top && $w.scrollTop() < $t.offset().top + $t.outerHeight() - allowance) {

              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 1,
                top: $w.scrollTop() - $t.offset().top
              });
            } else {
              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 0,
                top: 0
              });
            }
          }
        },
        repositionStickyCol = function() {
          if ($stickyWrap.scrollLeft() > 0) {
            $stickyCol.add($stickyInsct).css({
              opacity: 1,
              left: $stickyWrap.scrollLeft()
            });
          } else {
            $stickyCol
              .css({
                opacity: 0
              })
              .add($stickyInsct).css({
                left: 0
              });
          }
        },
        calcAllowance = function() {
          var a = 0;

          $t.find('tbody tr:lt(3)').each(function() {
            a += $(this).height();
          });

          if (a > $w.height() * 0.25) {
            a = $w.height() * 0.25;
          }

          a += $stickyHead.height();
          return a;
        };

      setWidths();

      $t.parent('.sticky-wrap').scroll($.throttle(250, function() {
        repositionStickyHead();
        repositionStickyCol();
      }));

      $w
        .load(setWidths)
        .resize($.debounce(250, function() {
          setWidths();
          repositionStickyHead();
          repositionStickyCol();
        }))
        .scroll($.throttle(250, repositionStickyHead));
    }
  });
});



function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByClassName("headcol")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
  *,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #3e5682;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

a {
  color: #31bc86;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #8f8888;
}

.container>header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
}

.container>header h1 {
  font-size: 2.625em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.container>header span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 60%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}


/* To Navigation Style */

.codrops-top {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.69em;
  line-height: 2.2;
}

.codrops-top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.codrops-top a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
}

.codrops-top span.right {
  float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.codrops-icon:before {
  font-family: 'codropsicons';
  margin: 0 4px;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.codrops-icon-drop:before {
  content: "\e001";
}

.codrops-icon-prev:before {
  content: "\e004";
}


/* Demo Buttons Style */

.codrops-demos {
  padding-top: 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.codrops-demos a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.7em 1.1em;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #31bc86;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.codrops-demos a:hover,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover {
  border-color: #7c8d87;
  color: #8f8888;
}

.related {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 25em) {
  .codrops-icon span {
    display: none;
  }
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Blokk';
  src: url('../fonts/blokk/BLOKKRegular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/blokk/BLOKKRegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/blokk/BLOKKRegular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/blokk/BLOKKRegular.svg#BLOKKRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.component {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 3em;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.component .filler {
  font-family: "Blokk", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #d3d3d3;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

td.err {
  background-color: #e992b9;
  color: #3e5682;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}

th {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3e5682;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tbody th {
  background-color: white;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(2n-1) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #b8b8b8;
}


/* For appearance */

.sticky-wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-col,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 50;
  width: auto;
  /* Prevent table from stretching to full size */
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead {
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.1em -0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  /* Force stretch */
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 150;
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect th {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #eee;
}

.sticky-wrap td,
.sticky-wrap th {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Not needed for sticky header/column functionality */

td.user-name {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.sticky-wrap.overflow-y {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 60vh;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display:
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Letters.." title="Type in a letter">


  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">A</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">B</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">C</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">D</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">E</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">F</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">G</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">H</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">I</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">J</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">K</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">L</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">M</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
```

Comment: @ikiK hmm, doesn't seem to have quite fixed the issue. When I search and then scroll horizontally, the first column still reverts back to the original. Thanks for the attempt though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I haven't  changed anything, I just edited the question to make a snippet/fiddle as you said you couldn't. It is easier for everybody. I did take a short look at it but don't have more time now, also never used throttle-debounce, so I don't know whats going on there to be honest. Good luck. Maybe ill give it another try tomorrow. But this is bit too much code to go thru. You should try to pin-point the problem part.

Comment: Okay sounds good, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple line on end of your search function will fix everything:

```
$("table.sticky-col * th.headcol").html(filter);
```

Problem was that your sticky plugin or what ever it is, clones your original table and makes its own on scrool:

```
<table class="sticky-col" style="opacity: 1; left: 623px;">...
```

and that is what is shown on scroll as can been seen in dev tools, by targeting that new table and setting first `th.headcol` to your filter value from search input it will do what you need.

**EDIT:**

Well it was not that simple, it worked to show correct latter but when search bar was emptied it wasn't showing correct latter in all rows when they were all shown again on scroll. So it needs to be reverted back. So you need this:

```
        if (filter !== "") {
    $("table.sticky-col * th.headcol").each(function() {
    $(this).parent("tr").css("display", "");
      if ($(this).html() !== filter) {
        $(this).parent("tr").css("display", "none");
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("table.sticky-col * th.headcol").each(function() {
      $(this).parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
  }
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('table').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('thead').length > 0 && $(this).find('th').length > 0) {
      // Clone <thead>
      var $w = $(window),
        $t = $(this),
        $thead = $t.find('thead').clone(),
        $col = $t.find('thead, tbody').clone();

      $t
        .addClass('sticky-enabled')
        .css({
          margin: 0,
          width: '100%'
        }).wrap('<div class="sticky-wrap" />');

      if ($t.hasClass('overflow-y')) $t.removeClass('overflow-y').parent().addClass('overflow-y');

      $t.after('<table class="sticky-thead" />');

      if ($t.find('tbody th').length > 0) {
        $t.after('<table class="sticky-col" /><table class="sticky-intersect" />');
      }

      var $stickyHead = $(this).siblings('.sticky-thead'),
        $stickyCol = $(this).siblings('.sticky-col'),
        $stickyInsct = $(this).siblings('.sticky-intersect'),
        $stickyWrap = $(this).parent('.sticky-wrap');

      $stickyHead.append($thead);

      $stickyCol
        .append($col)
        .find('thead th:gt(0)').remove()
        .end()
        .find('tbody td').remove();

      $stickyInsct.html('<thead><tr><th>' + $t.find('thead th:first-child').html() + '</th></tr></thead>');

      var setWidths = function() {
          $t
            .find('thead th').each(function(i) {
              $stickyHead.find('th').eq(i).width($(this).width());
            })
            .end()
            .find('tr').each(function(i) {
              $stickyCol.find('tr').eq(i).height($(this).height());
            });


          $stickyHead.width($t.width());


          $stickyCol.find('th').add($stickyInsct.find('th')).width($t.find('thead th').width())
        },
        repositionStickyHead = function() {

          var allowance = calcAllowance();


          if ($t.height() > $stickyWrap.height()) {

            if ($stickyWrap.scrollTop() > 0) {

              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 1,
                top: $stickyWrap.scrollTop()
              });
            } else {

              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 0,
                top: 0
              });
            }
          } else {

            if ($w.scrollTop() > $t.offset().top && $w.scrollTop() < $t.offset().top + $t.outerHeight() - allowance) {

              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 1,
                top: $w.scrollTop() - $t.offset().top
              });
            } else {
              $stickyHead.add($stickyInsct).css({
                opacity: 0,
                top: 0
              });
            }
          }
        },
        repositionStickyCol = function() {
          if ($stickyWrap.scrollLeft() > 0) {
            $stickyCol.add($stickyInsct).css({
              opacity: 1,
              left: $stickyWrap.scrollLeft()
            });
          } else {
            $stickyCol
              .css({
                opacity: 0
              })
              .add($stickyInsct).css({
                left: 0
              });
          }
        },
        calcAllowance = function() {
          var a = 0;

          $t.find('tbody tr:lt(3)').each(function() {
            a += $(this).height();
          });

          if (a > $w.height() * 0.25) {
            a = $w.height() * 0.25;
          }

          a += $stickyHead.height();
          return a;
        };

      setWidths();

      $t.parent('.sticky-wrap').scroll($.throttle(250, function() {
        repositionStickyHead();
        repositionStickyCol();
      }));

      $w
        .load(setWidths)
        .resize($.debounce(250, function() {
          setWidths();
          repositionStickyHead();
          repositionStickyCol();
        }))
        .scroll($.throttle(250, repositionStickyHead));
    }
  });
});



function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  //console.log(filter);
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByClassName("headcol")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

  if (filter !== "") {
    $("table.sticky-col * th.headcol").each(function() {
    $(this).parent("tr").css("display", "");
      if ($(this).html() !== filter) {
        $(this).parent("tr").css("display", "none");
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("table.sticky-col * th.headcol").each(function() {
      $(this).parent("tr").css("display", "");
    });
  }


}
```

```css
  *,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #3e5682;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

a {
  color: #31bc86;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #8f8888;
}

.container>header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
}

.container>header h1 {
  font-size: 2.625em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.container>header span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 60%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}


/* To Navigation Style */

.codrops-top {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.69em;
  line-height: 2.2;
}

.codrops-top a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.codrops-top a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
}

.codrops-top span.right {
  float: right;
}

.codrops-top span.right a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.codrops-icon:before {
  font-family: 'codropsicons';
  margin: 0 4px;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.codrops-icon-drop:before {
  content: "\e001";
}

.codrops-icon-prev:before {
  content: "\e004";
}


/* Demo Buttons Style */

.codrops-demos {
  padding-top: 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.codrops-demos a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.7em 1.1em;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #31bc86;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.codrops-demos a:hover,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo,
.codrops-demos a.current-demo:hover {
  border-color: #7c8d87;
  color: #8f8888;
}

.related {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 25em) {
  .codrops-icon span {
    display: none;
  }
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Blokk';
  src: url('../fonts/blokk/BLOKKRegular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/blokk/BLOKKRegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/blokk/BLOKKRegular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/blokk/BLOKKRegular.svg#BLOKKRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.component {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 3em;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.component .filler {
  font-family: "Blokk", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #d3d3d3;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.75em 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

td.err {
  background-color: #e992b9;
  color: #3e5682;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
}

th {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3e5682;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

tbody th {
  background-color: white;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(2n-1) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #b8b8b8;
}


/* For appearance */

.sticky-wrap {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-col,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 50;
  width: auto;
  /* Prevent table from stretching to full size */
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead {
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.1em -0.1em rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  /* Force stretch */
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 150;
}

.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect th {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #eee;
}

.sticky-wrap td,
.sticky-wrap th {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Not needed for sticky header/column functionality */

td.user-name {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.sticky-wrap.overflow-y {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 60vh;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display:
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Letters.." title="Type in a letter">


  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
        <th>Something</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">A</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">B</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">C</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">D</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">E</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">F</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">G</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">H</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">I</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">J</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">K</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">L</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">M</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
```

Comment: I just realized that it's so close. If the <th> remain one letter ("A" "B" "C"...) it works beautifully. If I start adding ones with more than one character (such as "AZ") and then search that, the sticky column stops working. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1580462 That is different question that has nothing to do with question asked. That behavior that you are talking about has been there before, as seen in your question snippet. I solved your problem from this question. I lost couple of hours on this, so feel free to ask another question with this "new" problem that you just noticed, maybe someone else has more time. It is also not alright that you removed solved check-mark from this, I put hours and effort in solving it, and I did solve what was asked. You can not just add new features to questions.

Comment: @user1580462 And to clarify, this new problem has nothing to do with sticky, it has to do with your search logic, sticky part only react to scrolling as I see it. When you just search for AB, it wont bring any results. That is the way you code it. Cose it searches for AZ in one column. Not, A or Z in all.

Comment: Ahhh okay, I'm sorry. I'll hit the check again. Again, I haven't used this site much. Guess I don't understand proper etiquette on it.