# Replace <td> number with a number that multiplies the original by .75

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a table in html that has a *ton* of data that I don't want to change by hand. I basically have to update every single  by a factor of .75. I figured the best way to do that would be to write a javascript function that takes the initial value of , multiplies it by .75, and then replaces it—but I'm stuck.

So, for instance, here's part of my table:

```html
<tr>
  <th class="headcol">PT 89</th>
  <td id="test">100</td>
  <td id="test">99</td>
  <td id="test">98</td>
  <td id="test">*</td>
  <td id="test">97</td>
  <td id="test">96</td>
  <td id="test">95</td>
  <td id="test">94</td>
  <td id="test">93</td>
  <td id="test">92</td>
</tr>
```

Here's the javascript I tried running, but it didn't work:

```js
function product() {
  let num1 = document.getElementById("test")
  let sum1 = num1 * 0.75
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = sum1
}
```

Does anyone have any tips?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "id" attribute values have to be **unique** within a given HTML page.

Comment: You will need to loop over each and pull the content with `.textContent`, then `parseInt` and then you can multiply and place it back into the `.textContent`

Comment: @mountaindrew ahhh, Thank you!

Comment: @Pointy - oh, okay, would "class" work? I could make it - getElementByClassName

Comment: Yes, `getElementsByClassName()` will return a **list** of elements, and then you'd iterate through that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you tagged this with jQuery so here is simple solution without changing current HTML markup:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".headcol").siblings("td").each(function() {
$(this).text(Math.round(parseFloat($(this).text()) * 0.75 || $(this).text())||$(this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <th class="headcol"> PT 89</th>
  <td id="test">100</td>
  <td id="test">99</td>
  <td id="test">98</td>
  <td id="test">*</td>
  <td id="test">97</td>
  <td id="test">96</td>
  <td id="test">95</td>
  <td id="test">94</td>
  <td id="test">93</td>
  <td id="test">92</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

to round it as requested, just wrap it into `Math.round` just like it is wrapped in `parseFloat`, So first you take text, convert into floating number, do calculation and then round it.

`Math.round` is like `parseFloat` is pure JS but you can easily apply it to selected value with jQuery. It would be maybe clearer if its done step by step, but one-liners are also popular ;)

Also to clarify it, `|| $(this).text()` part on `Math.round` and `parseFloat` is to return text if its not a number, in your case `*`

Comment: This is the best way that I can see.  In a real example, each of the ids would probably be different, as could the classes.  This method only looks for the table cells, regardless of id or class.

Comment: @ikiK do you know how I could round this to the nearest whole integer? I'm not sure how to add the math.round() to jQuery

Comment: @user1580462 np, please consider marking this answer as accepted on check-mark to mark the question solved for others.

Comment: @ikiK done. Sorry, I'm new here. Any chance you can take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/62747067/1580462?sem=2 . I'm genuinely stumped and could really use some help.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function product() {
  const tds = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
  tds.forEach(td => {
    const value = +td.textContent * 0.75;

    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      td.textContent = value;
    }
  });
}

product();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> <!-- Ignore this -->

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <!-- Never use duplicate id attribute, use class instead -->
    <th class="headcol"> PT 89</th>
    <td class="test">100</td>
    <td class="test">99</td>
    <td class="test">98</td>
    <td class="test">*</td>
    <td class="test">97</td>
    <td class="test">96</td>
    <td class="test">95</td>
    <td class="test">94</td>
    <td class="test">93</td>
    <td class="test">92</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```